# Increment A String in a column with oracle sequence

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I need some help with sequencing already filled table with string data.
So I have a COMP_ID with occurence like,

TC0001
TC0002
TC0003

So when user inputting a new row it should start with TC0004 etc..
I am just starting oracle and i dont know how to approach this using sequence. as far as i know sequence only works with int data type.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE CREATE SEQUENCE yourtable_sequence
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
NOCACHE
NOCYCLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER yourtable_trigger  
BEFORE INSERT ON yourtable
FOR EACH ROW


BEGIN
  SELECT 'TC000' || to_char(yourtable_sequence.NEXTVAL)
  INTO   :new.COMP_ID
  FROM   dual;
END;
```

Comment: Using a sequence like this is ok but I think the OP would expect that the `000`s are replaced by the number from the sequence, otherwise it will result in values like `TC00010`, `TC00011`, ... `TC000100`, etc. So instead, I'd suggest creating the sequence with a max value of 9999, and set the column using the expression `'TC' || TO_CHAR(yourtable_sequence.NEXTVAL,'fm0000')`.